# Using a url query string to jump to page sections

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

The standard tutorials teach how to use the hashtag and the anchor name to link to page sections, like so:

```
<li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>

<h1>Title</h1>

<a name="section1"></a><h2>Section 1</h2>
<p>Blah bla bla bla bla.</p>

<a name="section2"></a><h2>Section 2</h2>
<p>Blah bla bla bla bla.</p>
```

How do I make a page jump where I can embed the link to the page section using a fully qualified url? For example:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomein.com/page1?section=section2">Please read section 2</a>
```

The application is a signup notification email.

Comment: Isnt it ID and not name to make this work?

Comment: @DavidJones `name` or `id` will work, though `id` is valid for any type of element whereas these days `name` is intended for form elements. In other words, OP should be using `id` instead of `name`, but for backwards compatibility, `name` will work.

Comment: @David Jones : Huh. I use name, but I see tuts that use id. Interesting. I guess you can use both.

Comment: @AndréDion, Yeh I have always and probably always will use ID, thought it was worth mentioning, didnt know that name works in forms though so cheers for pointing that out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using your example, the link would be:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomein.com/page1#section2">Please read section 2</a>
```

Also note that the `<a name="section2"></a>` is superfluous. You could simplify to

```
<h2 id="section2">Section 2</h2>
```

Comment: Excellent, @André Dion.

Comment: I'm particularly happy to learn that any `id` will do. I thought you had to rely on the HTML author adding `<a name>` tags; `id` attributes are more ubiquitous.